# How to test Laravel Eloquent collections without touching the database?

Tags: php, testing, laravel, phpunit, eloquent

How do I unit test a Repository that grabs an Eloquent model and subsequently uses a collection method, but WITHOUT touching the database?

For example: if I have a method processUsers($ids), this method could use an eloquent collection method to process them. If there are thousands of users, I may use the `$users->chunk(50, function($myUsers) { // process 50 at a time only })` functionality to process the users. However, for me to use that, I would have to actually make a call to the database. How would I mock the database fetch, but still use the chunk() method?

Comment: Did you try Mockery? `$this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'Users');`

Comment: What do you mean? I want to actually do the chunking, without touching the database, so I don't want to mock the `chunk` method. I DO want it to use dummy data, though, so as not to touch the database.

Comment: You're looking for a way to mock Laravel models essentially. This is notoriously tricky to do. I have resorted to setting up SQLite db's for my testing environment due to the huge amount of hacking around you need to do to actually mock a model.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support all the data types that MySQL does, so I'd have to change my schema. It also makes the testing much slower.